# Accessing the bit bucket branches and their contents programmatically

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I need to list out the contents of a bitbucket branch. I am able to see the branch when I run the below code but am unable to figure out how to enter the branch. Giving the branch id is also not helping. The code so far:

```
package com.bitbucket.test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
//import com.atlassian.bitbucket.branch.model.*;

public class BitBucketPluginTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL bb = new URL("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{reponame}");
        URLConnection bbcon = bb.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                bbcon.getInputStream()));


        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

I have removed the repo name due to security issues. I am getting the data in JSON format currently. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "enter the branch"?

Comment: getting the commits into that branch of the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `start` argument to the [GET a list of changesets](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/changesets-resource-296095208.html#changesetsResource-GETalistofchangesets) endpoint:

https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jespern/django-piston/changesets?start=0.2.2-maint

Comment: It worked. I am able to get the list of files within the repository and its branches.